# making text above a line on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project where I am trying to make a text above a line on the image on all browser sizes. This will be more clear once you see the codpen link below.

The problem I am facing now is that once I set the top value to the right position and change the browser width, the text doesn't become above the line anymore.

```css
#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 685px;
}

html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


#background_pic
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<image src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/4/47/Horiz-line.JPG/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/600?cb=20050929041542" id="background_pic"></image>

<div id="text">
hello world
</div>
```

Comment: Codepen link does not work.

Comment: @Toolbox you have to scroll down to see the line

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites. Just include your code in a "code snippet", right here in your question.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just make the black line with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You set the `#text` to a static position from the top, which will not work on all screen sizes (which may vary), which will cause the image to vary.

You want to dynamically set the text based on the image height. Here is an example using JavaScript:

```js
function setTextPosition() {
  // get html elements
  var image = document.querySelector('#background_pic');
  var text = document.querySelector('#text');
  
  // get height of image
  var imageHeight = image.clientHeight;

  // dynamically set text position (the '-20' is meant to make the text stay above the line)
  text.style.top = imageHeight/2 - 20 + 'px';
}


// set the text position on load and resize
window.addEventListener('load', setTextPosition);
window.addEventListener('resize', setTextPosition);
```

```css
#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 685px;
}

html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


#background_pic
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<image src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/4/47/Horiz-line.JPG/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/600?cb=20050929041542" id="background_pic"></image>

<div id="text">
hello world
</div>
```

Try the above snippet, and see how resizing it always allows the text to stay right above the line.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Wow that was fast. Was just about to create a snippet from it.

Comment: Please just post your working solution, right here in your answer inside of a "code snippet". This makes it easier for us all to see your answer and ensures that it will always be accessible in the future.

Comment: im getting style not define

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at setTextPosition

Comment: @halmos That means that the document is not fully loaded. Are you using the `window.addEventListener('load', setTextPosition);` event listener to make sure that the page is loaded first?

Comment: @halmos That is strange. That means that the `text` variable is null. In your code, try logging the value of `document.querySelector('#text')` (the text element variable). Does the snippet in this answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If all you really want is text above a black line that has a radius on each end, then you can accomplish much simpler with just CSS.

By wrapping the text and the line in another element, you can then create space above and below the two:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin:100px 0;
}

.underline {
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Hello World!</div>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @halmos Then, what is the case? It appears that this is what you are doing.

Comment: the problem is much comlicated than presented look so far @Johnatan is on the right track. refer to his response